# can't receive the array to model

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

I'm receiving the following array to a flutter app through a model.

```
[
    {
        "shopid": "5e898e320328500017c589dd",
        "shopname": "f",
        "refID": "5e4e33e512e82b0017da6c04",
        "refName": "test",
        "_id": "5e8f3a6c5936e90017e294c8",
        "saledata": [
            {
                "_id": "5e8f3a6c5936e90017e294c9",
                "brand": "bdgbf",
                "model": "gbgvffgf",
                "capacity": "11gb",
                "imei": "84788585",
                "price": "414141"
            }
        ],
        "total": "414141",
        "saletime": "2020-04-09T20:40:31.212Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

I can retrieve everything except `saledata` to the following modal. And that works fine. 
The problem is getting the `saledata` I want retrieve that array too.

```
class SaleItem {
  String shopID;
  String saleID;
  String total;
  String shopname;
  String saletime;
  String refid;
  String refname;


  SaleItem(
      {this.shopID,
      this.saleID,
      this.total,
      this.shopname,
      this.saletime,
      this.refid,
      this.refname,
      });

  factory SaleItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SaleItem(
        shopID: json["shopid"] as String,
        saleID: json["_id"] as String,
        total: json["total"] as String,
        shopname: json["shopname"] as String,
        saletime: json["saletime"] as String,
        refid: json["refID"] as String,
        refname: json["refName"] as String,      
        );
  }
}
```

I tried to get this as `Object` but it did not work. How can I receive this `saledata` to my modal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class SaleItem {
  String shopID;
  String saleID;
  String total;
  String shopname;
  String saletime;
  String refid;
  String refname;
  List<SaleData> saleData;


  SaleItem(
      {this.shopID,
        this.saleID,
        this.total,
        this.shopname,
        this.saletime,
        this.refid,
        this.refname,
        this.saleData
      });

  factory SaleItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SaleItem(
      shopID: json["shopid"] as String,
      saleID: json["_id"] as String,
      total: json["total"] as String,
      shopname: json["shopname"] as String,
      saletime: json["saletime"] as String,
      refid: json["refID"] as String,
      refname: json["refName"] as String,
      saleData: (json['saledata'] as List)
          ?.map((i) => SaleData.fromJson(i))
          ?.toList(),

    );
  }


}


class SaleData {
  String sId;
  String brand;
  String model;
  String capacity;
  String imei;
  String price;

  SaleData(
      {this.sId, this.brand, this.model, this.capacity, this.imei, this.price});

  SaleData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    brand = json['brand'];
    model = json['model'];
    capacity = json['capacity'];
    imei = json['imei'];
    price = json['price'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['_id'] = this.sId;
    data['brand'] = this.brand;
    data['model'] = this.model;
    data['capacity'] = this.capacity;
    data['imei'] = this.imei;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    return data;
  }
}
```